# std::chrono::high_resolution_clock - time measurement

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

I'm learning < chrono > right now and I don't understand one thing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int a = 0;
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto result = t2 - t1;
    std::cout << result.count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Value of "result" in this case equals "0".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    int a = 0;
    auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto result = t2 - t1;
    std::cout << result.count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And in this case "result" equals about "5500".

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

No.  It's just that different clocks can have different precisions, and timing something so short might not take more than 1 tick of a clock.

You can find out a clock's precision by inspecting `clock::duration::period::num` and `clock::duration::period::den`.

Additionally, some implementations of `<chrono>` have had "quality of implementation" issues over the years.  So your experience might change as you switch compilers, and even versions of the same compiler.  Your experience will generally be better if you can work with the latest version of your compiler.

[Here is a video tutorial for `<chrono>`.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M)

Comment: I know about different precisions, but when I'm trying to "cout" precision of high_resolution_clock it is equal to steady_clock's one. Is it possible that "int a = 0;" takes less then 1 nanosecond or something?

Comment: @PaulNewman: It is more likely that your std::lib's implementation of `high_resolution_clock` isn't very good.  VS-13?  Can you upgrade to VS-15 or VS-17?  On my platform, consecutive calls to `high_resoluiton_clock` and `steady_clock` always output an updated value (even with nothing in-between the calls to `now`).

Comment: I'm using gcc 6.1.0 compiler actually.

Comment: Interesting.  This is the first report I've seen of this behavior with that compiler.  It leaves me wondering if the compiler has done some "creative" optimizations with the calls to `now`.  Another possibility is that the implementation of `high_resolution_clock` is calling something with only microseconds precision under the hood, and just bragging about nanosecond precision.

Comment: Do repeated calls to `high_resolution_clock::now()` always produces `time_points` containing nanoseconds that are integral amounts of microseconds?

Comment: High_resolution_clock::now() printed 10 times gives exactly the same value.

Comment: Interesting.  Not replicating here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/hptdOXMjHrgesM36  It might be that gcc on your platform is configured to use a crappy clock for `high_resolution_clock`, but not at the wandbox link I'm showing.

Comment: So changing compiler is the only one rational solution?

Comment: Or changing clocks.  `steady_clock` seems to be working for you, right?

Comment: In your `high_resolution_clock` output, are the last 3 decimal digits always `0`?

Comment: It's weird. Now, with 100 times, result is more interesting: [link](https://pastebin.com/KCFabwHF)

Comment: That is one lousy clock.  It is ticking at the rate of once per 0.015625s.  I've got a grandfather pendulum clock that does nearly that good. ;-)

Comment: So what should I do? :/

Comment: File a bug.  Use `steady_clock` unless you need to time something longer than .5s, or need a datetime with a precision of not more than .01s.  I don't know if upgrading your gcc, or switching to clang would help.  Ultimately the std::lib has to depend on the underlying hardware, which I know nothing about on your platform.

Comment: Fwiw, your `high_resolution_clock` is reporting nanoseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, and is a `typedef` for your `system_clock`.

Comment: So I think that the only one rational solution is to use steady_clock. :)